# How to Assign 0 if Calculated Value is <0 within CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table named **users** containing simple counts for all users.

| user_id | counter1 | counter2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | 3 | 8 |

I would like to run a single query that updates the counter1 values to counter1-# or 0 (# can be any whole number), whichever is greater for possibly multiple users.  The counter1 column is an unsigned int type.

I am executing the following query to update users 2 and 3:

```
UPDATE 
   users 
SET 
   counter1 =   CASE user_id 
                WHEN 2 THEN GREATEST(counter1 - 2, 0) 
                WHEN 3 THEN GREATEST(counter1 - 5, 0) 
                ELSE counter1 END
WHERE user_id IN(2, 3);
```

Running the above query returns an error:

**BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`user`.`counter1` - 2)'**

The end result I'm trying to aim for is for both user 2 and user 3 to have a minimum counter1 value of 0 after the query is executed since in both users' cases, subracting 2/5 from their counter1 values will be a negative number, which of course won't work.

Is there a way to do this with a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the expression `counter1 - 2` produces a negative value when `counter1` is less than 2. But since it's declared `UNSIGNED`, the result of expressions that use it are also unsigned, so negative values are not allowed.

Instead of subtracting from it, use an `IF()` expression to prevent calculating these invalid values.

```
CASE user_id
    WHEN 2 THEN IF(counter1 > 2, counter1 - 2, 0)
    WHEN 3 THEN IF(counter1 > 5, counter1 - 5, 0)
    ELSE counter1
END
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is:

```
GREATEST(0, CASE ... END)
```